# How to display multiple layers with Deck.gl

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, deck.gl

I am trying to make an interactive chart using Deck.gl that combines a HexagonLayer (for population data) with an IconLayer (for locations of a retail chain).

The deck.gl [documentation](https://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/getting-started/using-layers?section=rendering-multiple-layers) indicates that it is possible to render multiple layers on top of each other:

> deck.gl allows you to render multiple layers using the same or
>   different data sets. You simply provide an array of layer instances
>   and deck.gl will render them in order (and handle interactivity when
>   hovering clicking etc).

There is even an example of how the layers object can be initialized:

```js
<DeckGL layers={[
  new PathLayer({data: ...}),
  new LineLayer({data: ...}),
  new ArcLayer({data: ...}),
]} />
```

But I cannot figure out how to load separate data sources and initialize the two layers, all the examples are written as single layer demos.

Is anybody aware of any examples that actually combine multiple layers?

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the [deckgl-overlay](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/examples/trips/deckgl-overlay.js) file, the one that is used to render the header on the main [website demo](https://uber.github.io/deck.gl), which shows an usage using a custom `TripsLayer` and a `PolygonLayer`.

The data is encoded for portability, so it's not particularly readable, but I think your problem is that you are trying to use different layers using the same data structures, which is not *necessarily* compatible.

Here is an example using multiple layers:

```
const layers = [
  new ArcLayer({
    id: 'arc-layer',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    data: [
      { sourcePosition: [-122.4, 37.7843], targetPosition: [-122.416, 37.781], color: [255, 0, 255] },
    ],
  }),
  new ScatterplotLayer({
    id: 'scatterplot-layer',
    data: [
      { position: [-122.4, 37.78], radius: 5, color: [0, 255, 0] },
    ],
    radiusScale: 100,
  }),
  new LineLayer({
    id: 'line-layer',
    strokeWidth: 10,
    data: [
      { sourcePosition: [-122.43, 37.79], targetPosition: [-122.416, 37.781], color: [255, 0, 0] },
    ],
  }),
]
```

As you can see, the `ArcLayer` and `LineLayer` could use the exact same `data` object since  they have the same form, but a `ScatterplotLayer` can't do the same. You have to pay attention to the docs of each layers (eg the [ArcLayer](https://uber.github.io/deck.gl/#/documentation/layer-catalog/arc-layer) one), where an example data is shown.

<sub>Disclaimer: I work for Uber in the Data Visualization team that made deck.gl.</sub>

Comment: That docs link is broken but indeed adding `id: 'layer2'` and `id: 'layer1'` solved this for me, thanks for making deckgl.